# Material-UI: the value provided `undefined` is invalid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use **Tabs**, **Tab** and **Appbar** from  material ui 1.0.0-beta.35 to display some tabs with labels imported from an object with data.

I get this error from material-ui:

```
Warning: Material-UI: the value provided `undefined` is invalid
```

I could reproduce it in this **codesandbox** (material ui 1.0.0-beta.38 but same error):

[code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rl9w5wkovq)

Click "Console" to see the errors.
I have followed the guidelines as far as I can see? :

https://material-ui-next.com/api/tabs/

https://material-ui-next.com/api/tab/

https://material-ui-next.com/api/app-bar/

On the real project this causes the appbar to not function when I click the tabs. It did work for some time, but then this error happened out of the blue, but I haven't been able to find what is causing the error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the `Tabs` component, you're responsible for maintaining the selected tab in your state, that's the undefined `value` prop it is complaining about. So you'll need to do something like this:

```
class TabsContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedTab: 'shop-setup'
  }

  handleTabClick = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({selectedTab: value});
  }
  ..
      <TabsContent
          tabs={tabData}
          selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
          onChange={this.handleTabClick}
      />
  ..
}
```

and then pass `selectedTab` as `value` to `Tabs`:

```
const TabsContent = ({ tabs, selectedTab, onChange }) => {
  ..
        <Tabs value={selectedTab} onChange={onChange}>
  ..
};
```

Initialization is easier if you don't provide `value`'s for each `Tab` so the `selectedTab` simply becomes an index.

You're also going to want to lift the `RenderTab` definition out of `TabContent`, as it is created fresh on each render now, which will cause unnecessary remounting and possible loss of state.

UPDATE: here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2oq4xnokny)

Comment: Huge help.  Even just the _you're responsible_ was a good clue.  I was using tabs in the wrong way.